# Best way to update multiple documents at once in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I would like to update multiple couments by condtion in my nodejs backend using Mongoose

Trying to update seen notification for all users in the list.

My current method which works but involves lots of calls

```
  await notificationIDs.forEach(async noticeID => {
        await User.updateOne(
          { "notifications._id": noticeID },
          { $set: { "notifications.$.seen": true } }
        );
      });
```

Would like to update in one call

Answer (score 1):

To do this with one query, you can use [updateMany()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.updateMany) method with [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator:

```
await User.updateMany(
  { "notifications._id": {$in: notificationIDs} },
  { $set: { "notifications.$.seen": true } }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can update it using :

```
 await User.update({ "notifications._id": {$in: notificationIDs} },
                       { $set: { "notifications.$.seen": true } },
                       {multi: true});
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this with single query use db.collection.updateMany().

```
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    UserModel.updateMany({ "notifications._id": notificationIDs }, {$set: { "notifications.$.seen": true } }, { upsert: true, new: true }).exec((err, response) => {
        if (err) {
            reject({ status: 500, message: 'Internal Server Error', data: err });
        } else {
            resolve({ status: 200, message: 'Notification Updated Successfully.' });
        }
    });
});
```